# How can I force Fancytree to render hidden nodes with ext-table?

Tags: jquery, plugins, treeview, fancytree

I have two fancytree tables, and I can drag a node from one tree to the other. Once I drag the node I dynamically add a set number of children to the dragged node, which all have input fields in the next column, rendered via `renderColumn`.

The problem I'm facing is that the columns are not showing in my HTML until I manually expand the dragged node, and I need to validate the input fields associated to the children.

I tried iterating node by node and forcing each to render individually:

```
draggedNode.addChildren([
    //child nodes...
]);

draggedNode.children.forEach(function(childNode){
    childNode.render(true);
});
```

but to no avail... Is there a way to force these nodes to render? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jr52hw4g/2/) showcasing the issue.

Notice that when you drag a node from `tree1` to `tree2` 3 children are created for each "final" folder, however, were I to submit my form without first expanding the folders, there would be no rendered `<input>` tags to validate. You can verify this by looking at the HTML by pressing F12.